# Post multiple parameters one JSON string

Tags: c#, json, string, parameters

I am trying to post data to a json api.
this is how my code looks. It's returning an error from the server, the guys up there are telling me that i'm sending everything as a json string and that i should post params of which only one parameter is a JSON stirng. ie. contact_attributes which should contain a string like the one below:

> "{\"name\":\"Leigh\",\"surname\":\"Duddy\",\"passport_number\":\"
>   00000020\",\"unique_identifier\":\"7353280000000020\",\"msisdn\":
>   \"27829042259\",\"bank_account_number\":null,\"bank_account_br
>   anch_code\":null,\"bank_account_branch_name\":null,\"bank_detai
>   ls_required\":false,\"membership_number\":null,\"bank_account_b
>   ank_id\":null,\"bank_account_account_type_id\":null,\"bank_accou
>   nt_initials\":null,\"bank_account_surname\":null,\"bank_account_p
>   assport_number\":null,\"date_of_birth\":null,\"debit_day\":null,\"con
>   tract_sale_date\":null,\"contract_start_date\":null}"

I am totally confused, does anyone know how i can do this.

```
public class JsonSaleData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string contact_attributes { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string campaign_uuid = "9d119cce-25ea-46bc-b7bc-cba7e8323e91";
        [DataMember]
        public string user_credentials = "OCPdNbeltviij8C1RLcf";
        [DataMember]
        public string license_id = "1";

    }

private string PostSaleToClient(string url, JsonSaleData _SaleData)
        {


            string strResult = "";
            try
            {
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();


                System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";


                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonSaleData));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ser.WriteObject(ms, _SaleData);
                ms.Position = 0;
                String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());


                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                System.Net.HttpWebResponse httpWebResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                     strResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return strResult;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string e = ex.Message;
            }

           return strResult;


        }
```

Comment: you need to add parameter to write to the stream of the httpRequest, string postData = "data="+ jsonString; . and then write the post data string to bytes

Comment: Convert to string then send the straing to server side,Then you get the values by using reg-ex

Comment: Hi Ramesh. Thanks for responsing.  my customer whom i am posting sale details to can see my string but they are complaining that i am submitting everything as a json string. they say it should all be parameters of which the last parameter contains a Json string? any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to handle the JSON sring using following functions.

```
private string ConvertToJSON(objType obj)
  {

string sJSON = "{";

try {
    AppendToJSON(ref sJSON, "obj1Name", obj.obj1);
    AppendToJSON(ref sJSON, "obj2Name", obj.obj2);
    AppendToJSON(ref sJSON, "obj3Name", obj.obj3);
    AppendToJSON(ref sJSON, "obj4Name", obj.obj4);

    return sJSON.Substring(0, sJSON.Length - 1) + "}";

} catch (Exception ex) {
    return "";
}
 }
private void AppendToJSON(ref string byValJSON, string Name, string Value)
  {
byValJSON = byValJSON + "\"" + Name + "\":\"" + Value + "\",";
   }
```

And post the string to the server.

```
using System.Web;

public class AttributesHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
   {
string JSON = null;
string timeOut = null;

timeOut = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout;
try {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    JSON = ConvertToJSON(obj);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JSON);

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = timeOut;

} catch (Exception ex) {
}

   }
   }
```

call Using DotNet code:

```
string Url = "";
Url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/AttributesHandler.ashx?cd=xx";
object @out = null;
try {
Net.WebClient webclient = new Net.WebClient();
webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
@out = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((webclient.DownloadData(Url)));
} catch (Exception ex) {
//out = ex.InnerException.ToString
}
```

here they will get Response as string only.

Using Javascript Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", timeout: 60000, cache: false, dataType: "jsonp", url: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/AttributesHandler.ashx?cd=xx"         
    success: function (response) {
        objAttributes = response.Attributes; //in object formate
                if (objCardAttributes != null) {
         //can process the objects
               }
                 __doPostBack('upToolkit',);
          },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var sReturn = "Please close the browser and relaunch ";
        if (textStatus != null) { sReturn += " Details: (" + textStatus + ")"; }
        if (errorThrown != null) { sReturn += " Description: (" + errorThrown.Description + ")"; }
       __doPostBack('upToolkit', sReturn);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jaya Many thanks for the response, I have changed my code to generate the string using your methods, it is a much neater way than the way i was doing it, however i am still receiving the same error. HTTP Error 500 Internal server error. my customer whom i am posting sale details to can see my string but they are complaining that i am submitting everything as a string it should all be parameters of which the last parameter contains a Json string? any idea what this means?

Comment: your function's return type seems like string ,And I am updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jaya.. i used your ConvertToJSON method and got it to finally work, turns out i was building my json string totally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

your json and your POCO is not matching...it's not necessary to post multiple parameters to send data to server..but your json not translated to POCO in this case is problem

"{\"name\":\"Leigh\",\"surname\":\"Duddy\",\"passport_number\":\" 00000020\",\"unique_identifier\":\"7353280000000020\",\"msisdn\": \"27829042259\",\"bank_account_number\":null,\"bank_account_br anch_code\":null,\"bank_account_branch_name\":null,\"bank_detai ls_required\":false,\"membership_number\":null,\"bank_account_b ank_id\":null,\"bank_account_account_type_id\":null,\"bank_accou nt_initials\":null,\"bank_account_surname\":null,\"bank_account_p assport_number\":null,\"date_of_birth\":null,\"debit_day\":null,\"con tract_sale_date\":null,\"contract_start_date\":null}"

go to [www.json2csharp.com](http://www.json2csharp.com) see your json is not parsable...

make sure your json is right..

then using this site create csharp class and deserialize to that specific object